# Why Prefer Extended Events to sp_WhoIsActive and Query Store?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, extended-events, query-store, sp-whoisactive

If I want to find out what is happening *right now*, then I use Adam Machanic's `sp_whoisactive`. If I want to find out what has happened on my server *recently*, then I will use Query Store.

Extended Events were designed to replace the Profiler, but I would argue that the combination of Query Store and `sp_whoisactive` has already done that on any SQL Server on a 2016 or later version. **With that in mind, when would I ever use Extended Events?**

For inspiration, I checked the [Extended Events that dbatools comes with](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/tree/master/bin/XEtemplates). I was not impressed. They only seem useful for doing long-term monitoring of whatever Query Store does not store. For example: What certain logins are doing, locks, extremely specific types of IO, stored procedure parameter usage, and deprecated feature usage. Those are all well and good, but I frankly can't imagine myself ever having to do such surgical tuning on a server. Are there any commonplace usages that I have missed?

Comment: -3? Seriously? What is wrong with the question? If there is a fundamental flaw in the question, then I would like to know what. The last paragraph proves that I've attempted research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different tools for different jobs.

1. Query Store (QS) has aggregated query performance data for a single database.
2. WhoIsActive provides a snapshot of what's happening now on the server.
3. Extended Events (XE) provide over 2,400 events. While there is some overlap between XE, QS and Dynamic Management Objects (DMOs) - most XEs track information that isn't available elsewhere.

#### Things I'm using XE regularly for

- The SQL Server's audit tool is built on top of XE. I've created my own customised version to track only related changes
- Debugging Stored Procedure with branch logic, nesting and dynamic SQL. I can see which exact path the code took
- Monitoring Procedure timeouts across the whole server and gathering input parameters
- Monitoring blocking and deadlocking for later analysis
- Debugging AlwaysOn Availability issues
- Gathering SQL errors and parsing the call stack
- Watching for changes in Query Store settings

And many more.
It's one of my favourite tools and top tag on my blog - https://straightforwardsql.com/tags/extended-events/

Comment: Thank you. I read all of those blog posts with great interest. It seems like my general impression hasn't changed. Extended Events are for when you are tracking an extremely specific problem that no other source easily can. If I ever need to resort to them, then I'm having a bad day.

Answer (score 4):

> Extended Events were designed to replace the Profiler [...]

While that was part of the considerations, extended events were made to troubleshoot SQL Server in a more real-time and less invasive way along with bringing in the backend framework for auditing.

> [...] when would I ever use Extended Events?

How will sp_whoisactive or query store help you investigate a database taking a long time to start up? How will it help give you feedback from different query optimization or execution components? Which of those two items would help identify possible issues with backing up a database to cloud storage? Where is the bottleneck in AG synchronization?

> Are there any commonplace usages that I have missed?

Mentioned above are common items. It's also useful for understanding *how* SQL Server works and is helpful for diving in to the internals.

> Those are all well and good, but I frankly can't imagine myself ever having to do such surgical tuning on a server.

While you don't see yourself doing any of this right now, are you sure you won't in the future?

I've successfully used extended events to solve a plethora of issues, many times it needs coupled with other data to get the entire picture and understand what is *actually* happening.

Comment: "_How will it help give you feedback from different query optimization or execution components?_" - I'll happily grant the other points and I've given this a +1, but I'm sure that Query Store can be used for that particular task.

Comment: @J.Mini I didn't realize QDS gave you `query_optimizer_skip_memory_gateway` information.

Comment: So, bluntly, Query Store gives you plans and statistics, but those aren't always enough? That's a surprise. Plans and statistics are all that I've ever used for tuning. I must be profoundly ignorant of something quite important.

Comment: @J.Mini I try my best to stay away from that kind of stuff :D

Comment: So I'm ignorant because I'm lucky? That's new. I have much to learn, but it sounds like I won't learn it until I have a bad day.

Comment: @J.Mini If you want to see the type of stuff I typically get, feel free to read what I wrote about them. https://www.seangallardy.com/tag/olved-steries/